# Advanced MySQL database relationships

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is a bit of a silly question (probably) but I wasn't quite sure what exactly to search for or what this would be called in terms of MySQL databases.

Basically I want to take the next step in terms of MySQL databases. What I'd like to do (as an example) is let's say I have a table with articles and then another table with users. Each user can (for the sake of the example) "like" or "follow" an article. How would I do that in terms of MySQL? Could this be achieved by just doing normal relational databases? The best case scenario I can think of would be to have a seperate database called article_likes which contains the user's ID as well as the article's ID, but it seems clumsy.

Comment: You need a separate table `article_likes` not a separate database.

Comment: If the criteria for you is that you dislike it seeming clumsy for you, then do something different. Apart from that: You're in control, just do. @MahmoudGamal: It's not a problem to have relations across separate databases on the same server.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal yeah I meant table. Suffering from heat exhaustion!

Comment: @hakre No doubt that I am in control, the clumsy bit is really just to keep things neat (as I've had some run ins with people that shit on my head for ignoring common programming practices, lol). I just thought that maybe there was something I didn't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two entities: articles and users. And because each article can be 'liked' be many users and each user can 'like' many articles, this is what in normalization is called a many-to-many relationship (also called n:m).

In relational databases, you can not have these kind of relationships. To solve this problem you need to create an extra table which links both tables together. it would be something like users_articles where you would put the key (identifier) of users, the key of articles (identifier) and any additional information like date when it was followed, etc.

```
id_users_articles id_user   id_articles   date_added  status ....
1                 1         1             2012/11/01 ....
2                 1         2             2012/11/01 ....
3                 2         1             2012/11/01 ....
```

With such structure the many-to-many between users and articles becomes two many-to-one relationships:

1. Between users and users_articles
2. Between articles and user_articles.

Notice that the newly created table has two foreign keys (users, articles) but also good practice says that they have an id (auto incremented) on their own.

Comment: Hey man thanks. Yeah I figured that it would be something like that, I just thought that there was maybe some alternative way to do it, but this makes perfect sense anyway.